# adding custom css to a custom module

Tags: css, xml, magento, layout

I have created a custom module that I would like to add custom css styles to. I have done some research and found that the right way is to add the css to the correct folder and then use the layout.xml to add it.

My problem is that when I add the css I am returned with an error message:

```
Invalid method Namespace_Module_Block_Blockname::addCss(Array([0] => css/mystyle.css))
```

currently mystyle.css is in

```
skin/frontend/base/default/css/mystyle.css
```

I did try to add it to

```
Namespace/Module/css/mystyle.css but without success
```

My layout file is set out as follows

```
    <handle>
        <block type="modulename/block" name="reference_name" output="toHtml" template="Namespace/Module/filename.phtml" >  
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheeet>css/mystyle.css</stylesheeet></action>      
            <block type="modulename/block" name="reference_name" output="toHtml" template="Namespace/Module/filename.phtml" />
        </block>
    </handle>
```

After reading designing_for_magento, I also tried wrapping it in a default handle, that produced a blank screen.

No errors were received prior to adding this command, what have I done wrong?

===EDIT===

I have now tried (in the  node I have also tried placing )

```
<user_preferences>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><link>css/normalize.css</link></action>       
        <block type="prefcentre/returnuser" name="prefcentre_returnuser" output="toHtml" template="ps/prefcentre/returnuser.phtml" >  
            <block type="prefcentre/preferences" name="prefcentre_options" output="toHtml" template="ps/prefcentre/preferences.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>   
</user_preferences>
```

the file has been in the previously mentioned place and

```
skin/frontend/default/module/css/mystyle.css
```

But that has not worked either

Answer (score 0):

The `addCss` line should be added in the HEAD part of your layout, not in your block definition.

For example :

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="addCss"><stylesheeet>css/mystyle.css</stylesheeet></action>      
</reference>
```

See : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have followed and implemented the examples as best I can. But have still failed to make it work. Please see my edit, any advice would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Can't really say much without seeing the whole code, but here's a few bottleneccks I noticed:

1. According to the layout, you are updating only the page user_preferences. Does this handle exist, have you defined it?
2. You are putting the block prefcentre/returnuser into the head section instead of body - is it supposed to be there?
3. Block prefcentre/preferences is a child of prefcentre/returnuser. getChildHtml('prefcenter_options');  ?> should be called inside of ps/prefcentre/returnuser.phtml template